# GPS route length estimate, accounting for uncertainty of positions

Tags: android, ios, gps

So, this is a common problem in apps that track your location over a journey (a run or cycle workout, for example).

Clearly GPS navigators have less trouble, since they can assume you snap to a point on a road - however, if you're running in the park, snapping to some road grid is going to give you totally crazy numbers.

The problem as far as I see it is to combine the great-circle distances between the waypoints, but taking into account the errors (accuracy values) such that you don't veer off course too far for a low-accuracy point. The rough implementation in my head involves plotting some bezier curve (using the velocity/bearing at the point to add spline direction and weight) and integrating over it.

However, clearly this is something people have sovled before. Anyone know of the implementations, or are they all buried in proprietary software?

**Bonus points** for anyone who can also use the (mostly) less accurate cell tower points (which come with different/out-of-sync timestamps, and no velocity or bearing information).

The eventual implementation will be in javascript or python, whichever is faster (I'm using SL4A,) but I'm looking for general algorithms here.

Answer (score 2):

To get everyone started, here is the naive algorithm, not using any velocity or bearing info.

The arc length `s` is calculable from the two (long, lat) pairs (the start and end waypoints) of the segment we'll start with, by the standard formula.

Assuming we've converted the value pairs into standard spherical coordinates `phi` and `theta` (here as arrays, so using `phi[0]` and `phi[1]` for locations 0 and 1) in radians, the arc length is just:

```
from math import sin, cos, arccos, sqrt

s = arccos(
  sin(phi[0]) * sin(phi[1]) * cos(theta[0] - theta[1]) + 
  cos(phi[0]) * cos(phi[1])
)
```

However, since we've got a massive horrid function, we need to use the chain rule to work out the first order errors, and we get the following monster for `delta_s`:

```
delta_s = (1.0 / abs(sin(s))) * (
  delta_phi[0] * abs(
    sin(phi[0]) * cos(phi[1]) -
    cos(phi[0]) * sin(phi[1]) * cos(theta[0] - theta[1])
  ) +
  delta_phi[1] * abs(
    sin(phi[1]) * cos(phi[0]) -
    cos(phi[1]) * sin(phi[0]) * cos(theta[0] - theta[1])
  ) +
  (delta_theta[0] + delta_theta[1]) * abs(
    sin(phi[0]) * sin(phi[1]) * sin(theta[0] - theta[1])
  )
)
```

We perform this operation on every pair of successive points in order, sum the `s`s, add the errors in quadrature as normal:

```
accumulator = 0.0
for error in errors:
  accumulator += error * error

journey_error = sqrt(accumulator)
```

and thus, we know the uncertainty on our rubbish distance estimate. (we can even keep the `accumulator` around to speed up the calculation if we add a few points on the end - as we could in practise with real time data.)

However, this is going to give us huge errors, and only a very fuzzy idea of how far we've actually gone. This can't be how actual GPS equipment estimates distances, as it would never be accurate enough unless it had amazing signal all the time:

[image: Rubbish approximation to the path]

What we need is some more nuanced path approximation, which only bends the path out of position for the type of inaccurate points shown, rather than diverting it completely and massively increasing the distance estimate — in asking the question I was hoping to find out how all the existing implementations (probably) do it!